# Angular not understanding the URL containing index.html#

Tags: angular, angular7

Let me describe my Use case.

I have a requirement to change the AngularJs code to angular 7.

The application contains a page for retrieving the password. The flow of retrieving password is as below.

1. Retrieve password form takes email as input from user and sends a request to the server
2. Server generates a temporary URL for resetting the password. and sends an email to the user which contains the link for resetting password.
3. The temporary link sent in email is in the format https://server_address/index.html#/reset-password?uid=user_id&t=token.

Now, The problem is:
Temporary link sent on email contains "index.html#" in the URL. But angular7 app base URL is http://angualar_app_url/#/. So Angular is not able to understand the address and it can't route to the page.

I don't have access to the server code so I have to do work around
    on the angular side only.

Can someone tell me the workaround so that I can route to a page whenever the user clicks on the temporary link sent on email

Comment: For future reference, when tagging posts, `angularjs`=/= `angular`.

Answer (score 0):

I used a solution to fix a similar problem. Even the user opens "https://server_address/index.html#/reset-password?uid=user_id&t=token", the constructor of your entry level module which is mostly named app.module.ts will definitely execute. What you should do is in that constructor, check the URL and if it is the reset password url, redirect the user to the correct route using angular router like below:

In your app.module.ts(or whatever you named it)

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private router:Router){
    if(location.href.indexOf("index.html/#/reset-password")>-1){     
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/resetpassword'); //the path where you actually want to navigate your user

    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you @Nabil Shahid . I have tried this solution, It works fine.

Comment: Ur welcome @shivshankaralkondwar. Please mark the answer as best answers so it can be closed and other users can consider it legitimate.